# Attribute option not working in woo-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am using the latest WordPress version with my WordPress (in woo-commerce). All of its features are working fine except the *ATTRIBUTE* option. Whenever I try to save, it shows only load option and nothing happens.

How can I resolve this. Any suggestions?

[image]

These errors appear in inspect element console.

Comment: Best guess based on info provided: you have an outdated plugin. Start with the error info you have which points you to whichever plugin is registering 'ultimate-woocomomposer-backend.min.js'. Consider that your theme could also be responsible.

Comment: Have resolved thankyou so much